# Next.js next-i18next is always routing to EN

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, next.js, i18next, next-i18next

I have a simple project that supposed to work with English and Dutch(default). I have copied everything from the original example but somehow it doesn't work as expected.

Even though I have `browserLanguageDetection: false`, it is forcing me to `/en`endpoint.

I would like to show the NL text on `/` but currently I couldn't.

Could you please check the sandbox and tell me what is wrong here?

https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-galileo-zifjm?file=/pages/index.js

Answer (score 2):

There is solution in the docs. Here it is: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing

As I found out from the docs you should declare **localeDetection: false** then you should declare your own domain paths. It will work.

```
i18n: {
 defaultLocale: 'en',
 locales: ['en'],
 
 localeDetection: false, // Important!

 domains: [
  {
   domain: 'example.com', // <-
   defaultLocale: 'en' // This locale will be appeared at the exact above domain.
  },
  {
   // 2nd locale goes here in the same way.
  }
 ]
}
```

I hope, it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to know that in Next.js, the first loading is always done on the server side. In `i18n.js` you have defined  `browserLanguageDetection: false` but you have not defined `serverLanguageDetection: false` that's why you are always redirected to `/en`

In the index page, replace this line  `export default withTranslation('common')(IndexPage);`  with this one `export default withTranslation(['common'])(IndexPage);`  to avoid this [warning](https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next/issues/79)